# Unit testing ensure one method calls another method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mocking, rhino-mocks

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Car car)
{
   _repository.CreateCar(car);
   _repository.UpdateRegistrationDetails(car);
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is write unit test to ensure that `Create` calls `CreateCar` and `UpdateRegistrationDetails`. It doesn't matter about what happens in these methods but just that they get called. Could someone please tell me how to do this? Do I need to use a mocking framework for this? I have RhinoMocks installed to use. Do you use the `Expect` in RhinoMocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again using Moq I think you need to mock the Repository instead (assuming names here of course)

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();

var controller = new Controller(mock.Object); //assuming this is how you create it

var car = new Car();
controller.Create(car);

mock.Verify(x => x.CreateCar(car));
mock.Verify(x => x.UpdateRegistrationDetails(car));
```

No need for `Setup` or `Expect` as the mocked methods do not return anything

[EDIT]
Here is a Rhino.Mocks example

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepository>();

var controller = new Controller(mock); //assuming this is how you create it

var car = new Car();
controller.Create(car);

mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateCar(car));
mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateRegistrationDetails(car));
```

Comment: Also make sure that either `_repository` is an interface or both methods are virtual

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to use a mocking framework as others here have mentioned. The dirty way, but sometimes faster if you don't want to learn mocking frameworks (which you really should) is to create a test class and override virtual methods. In your case something like

```
public class RepoUnderTest : Repo
{
    public bool UpdateRegistrationDetailsCalled = false;
    public override void UpdateRegistrationDetails(Car car)
    {
        base.UpdateRegistrationDetails(car);
        UpdateRegistrationDetailsCalled = true;
    }
}
```

then you can test something similar to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Car car)
{
   // Arrange
   var _repository = new RepoUnderTest();

   // Act
   _repository.CreateCar(car);

   // Assert
   Assert.IsTrue(_repository.UpdateRegistrationDetailsCalled);
}
```

Again a mocking framework is best. And I'd vote for those, but sometimes this is an easy introduction to testing for these things before you get heavier into mocking.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding using of `Expect()` in RhinoMocks. I preffer to use stubs and 'Stub()' or `AssertWasCalled()` methods as much as possible. `Expect()` is used in cases when nothing else works.